# Magento coupon discount rule using payment method

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, cart

I need to add a coupon discount after user select the payment method. I don't know what the best way to do this, I put this after the payment step or I add on the review step?

I try to add on the review but I can´t change the URL of post, when I send the form to calculate the discount this redirect to cart page. Someone has already implemented this functionality in Magento and can help me?

I use Magento 1.6.2!

EDIT:

I use the rule with payment methods. 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/228664/#t322601

And alter some features to add two or more cart rule using the same coupon code.

But I can't validate the coupon because the payment method is selected on onepage checkout and the coupon form is on the cart.

How can I do for fix this?

Comment: or http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/magento-promotions/-create-magento-promo-coupon-codes

Comment: This show how can create a rule, I need to remove the coupon form of the cart and add on onepage step. My business rule is: If the client use a determined coupon and pay with cash is a percent of discount, if the user user the same coupon code but pay with credt card, the discount is different!

Comment: I think not, I guess I need to add the form of discount coupon on review page to validate the coupon and verify that the payment method user chose to apply correct discount value...

Comment: see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/228664/#t322601

Comment: This can help me, thanks! But you know how I can create an action for each rule? I need the same coupon code apply all my rules and that every rule has an action.

Comment: you mean how to mass apply an action to all your rules?

Comment: see http://www.unchi.co.uk/2012/05/31/magento-mass-upload-shopping-cart-price-rules/

Comment: feel free to upvote an answer of mine for the help :)

Comment: you can also buy an extension to help you bulk update http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mass-product-actions-3300.html

Comment: I change the table and construct of Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Coupon and now I can add more than one rule with the same coupon code... But in my cart the rule using payment method not recognize... 

How does the recognition of which payment method you will use the time to validate the coupon if the payment method is chosen only after the coupon is added?